# Inno Setup - How to convert decimal number to hex?

Tags: inno-setup

I already know how to convert hex to decimal, but I can't figure out the opposite.
I need a function to convert a decimal value to hex then write it into the registry with RegWriteBinaryValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function for converting integer values to their hexadecimal notation at this time. Here is a function that can do that. `Value` is the number to convert. `Digits` indicates the minimum number of hexadecimal digits to return:

```pascal
[Code]
const
  HexDigits = '0123456789ABCDEF';

function IntToHex(Value: Integer; Digits: Integer): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Digits);
  for I := 0 to Digits - 1 do
  begin
    Result[Digits - I] := HexDigits[(Value and 15) + 1];
    Value := Value shr 4;
  end;
  while Value <> 0 do
  begin
    Result := HexDigits[(Value and 15) + 1] + Result;
    Value := Value shr 4;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```pascal
[Code]

function IntToHex2(Value: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%.8x', [Value]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
function IntToHex2(Value: Integer; Digits: Integer): string;
begin
    Result := Format('%.' + IntToStr(Digits) + 'x', [Value, Value]);
end;
```

Comment: Keep just one answer. This is just an improvements, not "another way".

Comment: Also, again, you use `[Value, Value]`, when there's only one format specifier. So it should be just `[Value]`.

Comment: Cleaner way to implement variable digits number using the `Format` function is `Result := Format('%.*x', [Digits, Value])`